# Struggling with php SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have used the below code in my website,

```
<?php 
$con= mysqli_connect("*******","******","*****", "catalejo_articles");      
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM baul");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['title'] . " " . $row['date'];  
}
mysqli_close($con);      
?>
```

and it is not working. What am i doing wrong??

I am new to php and mysql, any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I want to thank and apologize to all of you who spent precious time trying to help me. I just solved the problem, the original code was OK. The problem was I didn't change the file extension to PHP.

Comment: How it is not working? Any errors? Not the expecting results?

Comment: nothing happens, no errors, no result, nothing

Comment: Is there a reason you're not checking whether `mysqli_query` was successful?

Comment: check what output is your $row try print_r($row) in while follow http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

Comment: nope, its just that im new to this, what do you suggest, adding IF?

Comment: `$result= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM baul") or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: $con= mysqli_connect("*******","******","*****", "catalejo_articles") or die(mysqli_connect_errno()); remove the if condition and echo your query it'll be printed at browser window copy and paste into phpmyadmin or sqlyog then execute it see what it return.

Comment: Please see my answer. You were missing a bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure display error is enabled. add this line at the top of your page and see if it display any error :

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

And try inside while loop :

```
var_dump($row)
```

Does table contains data?

Comment: do you still get nothing no error no warning. Whats the output of var_dump($row) ?

Comment: i keep getting a blank page

Answer (score 0):

From what I can make out of your code, since you were attempting to reference by association instead of by numerical index, you weren't seeing anything because you were missing MYSQLI_ASSOC in your while loop:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  echo $row['title']." ".$row['date'];
}
```

Otherwise you need to know where "title" and "date" columns are located and reference them by numerical value:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row[0]." ".$row[1];
}
```

Alternatively, if mysqli_fetch_array is not working (due to PHP version), try using:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['title'].' '.$row['date'];
}
```

Comment: Updated answer to provide alternate means for same goal.

Comment: it just refuses to work, worst thing is I dont even get an error

Comment: These are all tested and working, it must be something wrong with either the server configuration or the spelling for which you're using to target the tables/databases you're attempting to read from.

Are you testing on a live domain or on a local dev environment?

Comment: Are you sure that your hosting provider supports PHP with the plan you're using?

Comment: yes they do, i set up mySQL this morning and they said "There is a delay while DNS updates for new hostnames" do you think this could be the cause?

Comment: It very well could be. Though if the error was in issue with your DNS not having flipped over:
`if (mysqli_connect_errno()) die(mysqli_connect_error());`
should have told you that the host was unreachable.

Comment: that's right so it looks like php is not working at all, however another page contains a contact form that works perfectly

Comment: Well, that's at least good news in a way. It can sometimes take up to 72 hours for DNS records to propagate globally based on the host's geographical location. Wait a day or two, then try some of what was already discussed here if you run into any snags. Best of luck!

Comment: I hope it really is the DNS, and not something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if u have any records in your table using mysqli_num_rows

```
$con= mysqli_connect("*******","******","*****", "catalejo_articles");        
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM baul");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count > 0)
    {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo $row['title'] . " " . $row['date'];  
    }
    }else{
    echo "No Records found in the table";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM baul", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo $row['title'] . " " . $row['date'];  
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: i keep getting a blank page

Comment: its already solved, the file extension was .html instead of .php